# SQL - n-tier Join statement

Tags: sql

I am joining an ancestor table to a query which gives expected results, but in a few cases, it returns multiple rows per 'client'.  I need to return only the line with the 'MAX' entry from a column.

```
SELECT      C.FULL_NAME_ALTERNATE || ' (' || C.CLIENT_NUMBER || ')' AS  CLIENT,
            SA.ORGANIZATION_ID                                  AS  SA_ORG,
            SA.PROGRAM_NAME                                     AS  PROGRAM,
            CPA.PROCEDURES                                      AS  PROCEDURE,
            SUM(SA.ACTIVITY_UNIT)                               AS  USED_UNITS,
            AP.DEFAULT_PROCEDURE_FEE                            AS  FEE,
            (SUM(SA.ACTIVITY_UNIT) * AP.DEFAULT_PROCEDURE_FEE)  AS  USED_DOLLARS,
            AP.ORGANIZATION_ID                                  AS  AP_ORG

FROM        RPT_CLIENT          C
INNER JOIN  RPT_CLIENT_PAYER_AUTH   CPA ON  C.CLIENT_ID = CPA.CLIENT_ID
INNER JOIN  RPT_SCHEDULED_ACTIVITIES    SA  ON  SA.ACTIVITY_DETAIL_ID = CPA.ACTIVITY_DETAIL_ID
INNER JOIN RPT_ORGANIZATION_RELATIVE    R   ON  R.DESCENDANT_ORG_ID = CPA.ORGANIZATION_ID
INNER JOIN  RPT_ADMIN_PROCEDURE     AP  ON  CPA.PROCEDURES =  AP.PROCEDURE_CODE                                                         
                                    AND (AP.END_DATE > CURRENT_DATE OR AP.END_DATE IS NULL)
                                    AND AP.ORGANIZATION_ID = R.ANCESTOR_ORG_ID

GROUP BY    C.FULL_NAME_ALTERNATE || ' (' || C.CLIENT_NUMBER || ')',
            SA.ORGANIZATION_ID,
            SA.PROGRAM_NAME,
            CPA.PROCEDURES,
            AP.DEFAULT_PROCEDURE_FEE,
            AP.ORGANIZATION_ID
```

This returns something like the following:

```
CL    ID   PROG  PROC   UNIT    DOLLARS     FEE    SA_ID
Bob  1029   ACH W7075   4069    37272.04    9.16    1029
Bob  1142   RCH W6099   344     5149.68     14.97   1142
Bob  1142   RCH W6099   344     5772.32     16.78   1137
Jen  1029   ACH W7074   3898    17541       4.5     1029
Jen  1024   BEH W7095   55      1068.1      19.42   1024
Jen  1142   RES W6099   343     5134.71     14.97   1142
Jen  1142   RES W6099   343     5755.54     16.78   1137
Dave 1186   RES W6098   350     64004.5     182.87  1137
Dave 1186   RES W6098   350     64004.5     182.87  1186
Dave 1186   RES W6099   350     5873        16.78   1137
Dave 1186   RES W6099   350     5873        16.78   1186
```

I need to return only 1 row per Client, ID, Program and Procedure.  When there are multiples, the line with max(sa_id) needs to be used.
*The sa_id and id do not always match, but when they do, they are to be selected.

---

Comment: Is `sa_id` a unique column, or are there multiple records with the same `sa_id` for the same client?  Sample data for the example output you gave would be helpful. :)

Comment: The column names in the example results, don't match the selected columns int eh query you provided.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to add a statement that filters out the sa records that are not the max sa record for your join clause as follows:

```
SELECT      C.FULL_NAME_ALTERNATE || ' (' || C.CLIENT_NUMBER || ')' AS  CLIENT,
            SA.ORGANIZATION_ID                                  AS  SA_ORG,
            SA.PROGRAM_NAME                                     AS  PROGRAM,
            CPA.PROCEDURES                                      AS  PROCEDURE,
            SUM(SA.ACTIVITY_UNIT)                               AS  USED_UNITS,
            AP.DEFAULT_PROCEDURE_FEE                            AS  FEE,
            (SUM(SA.ACTIVITY_UNIT) * AP.DEFAULT_PROCEDURE_FEE)  AS  USED_DOLLARS,
            AP.ORGANIZATION_ID                                  AS  AP_ORG

FROM        RPT_CLIENT          C
INNER JOIN  RPT_CLIENT_PAYER_AUTH   CPA ON  C.CLIENT_ID = CPA.CLIENT_ID
INNER JOIN  RPT_SCHEDULED_ACTIVITIES    SA  ON  SA.ACTIVITY_DETAIL_ID = CPA.ACTIVITY_DETAIL_ID
INNER JOIN RPT_ORGANIZATION_RELATIVE    R   ON  R.DESCENDANT_ORG_ID = CPA.ORGANIZATION_ID
INNER JOIN  RPT_ADMIN_PROCEDURE     AP  ON  CPA.PROCEDURES =  AP.PROCEDURE_CODE                                                         
                                    AND (AP.END_DATE > CURRENT_DATE OR AP.END_DATE IS NULL)
                                    AND AP.ORGANIZATION_ID = R.ANCESTOR_ORG_ID
and sa_id = (select max(sa_id) from RPT_SCHEDULED_ACTIVITIES x where x.ACTIVITY_DETAIL_ID = CPA.ACTIVITY_DETAIL_ID)

GROUP BY    C.FULL_NAME_ALTERNATE || ' (' || C.CLIENT_NUMBER || ')',
            SA.ORGANIZATION_ID,
            SA.PROGRAM_NAME,
            CPA.PROCEDURES,
            AP.DEFAULT_PROCEDURE_FEE,
            AP.ORGANIZATION_ID
```